# How to Configure the Windows Service Release Tasks like Install TopShelf Windows Service in VSTS?

Tags: windows-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on DevOps with VSTS. I created the simple windows service application using VS2015 for that I configured the release definition in VSTS by adding this tasks through this [Windows Service Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.windows-service-release-tasks).

I configured the **Start Windows Services**, **Install (TopShelf) Windows Service** and  **Stop Windows Services** tasks successfully.

Configuration of **Install (TopShelf) Windows Service**
[image]

During release the above **Stop** and **Install** tasks are run successfully but **Start** task failed with the following error.

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: No such services: FirstService

Because the Install(TopShelf) Windows Service task will not be installed an windows service in machine. But it simply succeded.

I have the few questions like

1. what is the difference between **Install(TopShelf) Windows Service** and **Install and Start Windows Service** VSTS release tasks.
2. If I used the **Install(TopShelf) Windows Service task**, It works only  if you have already existing windows service is running in virtual machine otherwise it will failed. But if I used the **Install and Start Windows Service** task, It will be installed new windows service in virtual machine. But I am unable to give Displayname and Description of the installed windows service.

Comment: What the detail release log (by setting `system.debug` = `true`)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, This is the onedrive link for release logs after setting system.debug is true.https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CwQRRC2UEqkA6UwrW

Comment: Can you also update the project you build or a sample project which has the same error message to one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, Those are the correct release logs.The above image will be only different but the configuration I did the same as above image.

Answer (score 3):

They are two extensions created by 3rd party. So you can search them in the VSTS Marketplace and get the detailed information for them.

For your question：

**Install(TopShelf) Windows Service**

This is used to install Topshelf service which created with [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) framework.

**Install and Start Windows Service**

This is used to install the general Windows Service via Power-Shell or InstallUtli.

So if you just create a general Windows Service from VS. You should use the second one.

And usually, to set the Display Name and Description for a Windows Service, you need to do it in your code. Please refer to this question for details: [What's the best way to set a windows service description in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485268/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-windows-service-description-in-net).

Comment: Thanks Eddie Chen, But I right now I don't have any code related to windows services because I am working on only drop given by client it contains respective dll and extensions etc.. then how I change Display Name and Description of the specified windows service. Is there any alternative way to change the Display Name and Description of windows service in VSTS release rather than you need to change code.

Comment: @pradeep There isn't any way to achieve this as far as I know. :(

Comment: @pradeep But you could consider to write your own build task and involve SC.exe to install the windows service. This will allow you to set the display name and description. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe

Comment: If you don't mine, Can you please update your answer with how to create your own build task with sc.exe and to set the display name and description

Comment: @pradeep Add a command line task to call the SC.exe to install the service or create your own build task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib